# Moving image from one SQL server table to another

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have two tables which store the same data. One is for active users and the other for inactive users. When a user comes, it is searched in the active table and if not found, it is searched in the inactive table. If the user info is found in the inactive table, then it should be moved to active table and deleted from inactive table. 
The tables have a column that stores a photograph. When I try to insert the information to active table, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with image
```

I am sure it is caused by the photo because if the user info does not have a photo, the move is successful. But when there is a photo, it fails with the above error.

The SQL that creates the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBackup](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DriverId] [int] NULL,
    [FirstNameAmh] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [FatherNameAmh] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [GrandNameAmh] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Photo] [image] NULL
)
```

Here is the code:

```
$dbc->beginTransaction();
$sql = "select * from tblBackup where Id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET["gid"]);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();
$ins = "insert into tblActive(Id, DriverId, FirstNameAmh, FatherNameAmh, GrandNameAmh, Photo) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$st = $dbc->prepare($ins);  
$val = array($row['Id'], $row['DriverId'], $row['FirstNameAmh'], $row['FatherNameAmh'], $row['GrandNameAmh'],  $row['Photo']);
$st->execute($val);

$sql = "delete from tblBackup where Id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET["gid"]);
$stmt->execute();

$dbc->commit();
```

**Edit:** 
I concluded that the photo data retrieved by PHP is being treated as nvarchar(max) type rather than image type by SQL server. Because of this, SQL server is complaining that it could not insert nvarchar(max) in image data type column. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to insert a image into an nvarchar field

Comment: The error is kind of deceiving. I am sure the photo column is set to `image` when the table is designed.

Comment: Ok, show us the table structure and the code

Comment: I have attached a simplified code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the development phase, I think it would be better to create a stored procedure including "insert select" with "gid" as the parameter and execute it from php. Can't it be a solution for you?

Comment: It is not in development phase, rather I am adding a web side to an existing system. But sure I can create stored procedures. I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a little bit and now it is working. It is seems the problem is cause by prepared statement, though I don't understand why.

```
$dbc->beginTransaction();
$sql = "select * from tblBackup where Id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET["gid"]);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();
$ins = "insert into tblActive(Id, DriverId, FirstNameAmh, FatherNameAmh, GrandNameAmh, Photo) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ".$dbc->quote($row['Photo']).")";

$st = $dbc->prepare($ins);  
$val = array($row['Id'], $row['DriverId'], $row['FirstNameAmh'], $row['FatherNameAmh'], $row['GrandNameAmh']);
$st->execute($val);

$sql = "delete from tblBackup where Id=?";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET["gid"]);
$stmt->execute();

$dbc->commit();
```